# I recently uninstalled and reinstalled python and I set it up but there is one problem

Tags: python, traceback

I set my python files to open via (python.exe) but they open a close really quick, I managed to record my screen and slow it down and caught this error:
[image]

Traceback (most recent call last):
With no error popping up, I spoke to friends about it and could not come to a conclusion, and my files have 0 error and work fine in terminal and vs code but when I double click it it doesn't seem to work.  Adding time.sleep() to the code doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: Possibly the terminal window closes before the rest of the traceback is rendered. try adding some `time.sleep()` in your scripts

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: You can try running the script in the console so it will keep the output, or pipe the output to a file

Comment: what do you expect it to show ?

Comment: A program that works it contains input and print commands so stuff should appear.

Comment: Open `cmd` and run your python code as `py myfile.py`

Comment: The thing is before I uninstalled and reinstalled it was working fine upon double-clicking.

Comment: The point is so I dont have to run it in terminal.